# CMS ipad App using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I'm new to iOS development and m curious to know how can i create a CMS app like flipboard or WiredMag for ipad???

i have basic knowledge of Objective C and its frameworks.

I need to know how to connect to internet and pick the stuff n display it on the ipad??

I've created some awesome animations that are used by Ipad Magazines,but how to collect the data from the internet???

Comment: c'mon guyz??

is it possible or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NSURLConnection or http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ to implement your own data fetching.

You should ideally have a server respond with JSON or XML format data and use either of the above classes to request and parse that.